# How to save an string using csv?

Tags: java, csv

I'm making a small Java program that creates can store Students using an array list. I save students have a function that saves the student data into the array.

```
students.add(new Student(studentID, studentName, studentCar, studentGender));
```

What I'm trying to do now is to do the same thing, although I want to create a function that will enable me to save students using CSV. For example, I want to save a student by typing into the console "2222342, John Williams, yes, male" . 
Is that possible to do?

Note that I'm using console in java for inputs and outputs.

Comment: *Is that possible to do?* Yes.

Comment: Yes, just grab the whole String, separate the parts, then use them like normal.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should give you an idea on how to the store the student object into an array of student.

> Note that setting the  Integer studentCount = 3; will determine how
>   many student to be input and store in the student array list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class student {

    private Integer studentID;
    private String studentName;
    private String studentCar;
    private String studentGender;

    public student(Integer studentID, String studentName, String studentCar, String studentGender)

    {
        this.studentID=studentID;
        this.studentName=studentName;
        this.studentCar=studentCar;
        this.studentGender=studentGender;

    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         Integer studentID;
         String studentName;
         String studentCar;
         String studentGender;
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  
         Integer studentCount = 3;

         ArrayList<student> students=new ArrayList<student>();//Creating students arraylist  

        for(int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++)
        {

            System.out.println("Enter Student Details:");
            String studentDetails=sc.next(); 

            String[] values = studentDetails.split(",");    

            studentID = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
            studentName = values[1];
            studentCar =values[2];
            studentGender = values[3];

            //add student from input to students array list
            students.add(new student(studentID,studentName,studentCar,studentGender));

         }
         //Print your array list of students
         for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
         {
               System.out.println("ID:" + students.get(i).studentID);
               System.out.println("Name:" + students.get(i).studentName);
               System.out.println("Car:" + students.get(i).studentCar);
               System.out.println("Gender:" + students.get(i).studentGender);
         }

    }


}
```